# VOLTTRON connect with Local cluster or (AWS)

Tags: volttron

Hi I am a developer who is studying VOLTTRON PLATFORM. 
I have problem about connecting volttron and local cluster(or AWS).

In document, I couldn't found about part of connection volttron with local cluster(or AWS).

I think there three case about this problem solving.

1. use vip(volttron interconnect protocol)<-- but this solution should install volttron
2. use http protocol <-- but this is not good solution for big data processing
3. use socket programming

solution 1 make customize agent for big data framework(Spark ,etc) interface

solution 2~3 make customize agent for connect to cloud

Would you recommend the way to solve this problem? or give some other solution ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to integrate with the message bus, or just connect to the historian to access data flowing out of the volttron platform?

Either are possible, and your use cases you layout are correct. I would avoid #3, as it's unnecessarily complex and has no benefit that I'm aware of.

I think we would need more context to make a specific recommendation for your use case.

If you only need access to read data out of your volttron deployment, integrating at the database level is probably ideal.

If you need to have input back into the volttron deployment, ie, operating actuators, you would need deeper integration at the VIP level, and I would recommend just writing an agent to accomplish what you want and running it within the volttron environment. You can easily deploy volttron to an EC2 host and access the other AWS resources from that agent.